# Google play services revision 18 can't detect Meta-data tag in manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, metadata, manifest

I am using google play services in my app. For ads only. I know i should add meta data tag but it is already written. And there is no errors visible anywhere. I wasted hours but couldn't solve.

It says everywhere to write Meta-data tag in manifest but i already have. I do something wrong (syntax) in AndroidManifest?

Here is the log cat message:

```
07-21 19:44:36.947: E/AndroidRuntime(26760): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 19:44:36.947: E/AndroidRuntime(26760): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.ZigZagMindGames.Bouncy/com.ZigZagMindGames.Bouncy.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does 
not have the right value.  Expected 5077000 but found 1.  You must have the following 
declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ZigZagMindGames.Bouncy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data  
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

integers.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


<integer name="google_play_services_version">1</integer></resources>
```

And MainActivity:

```
package com.ZigZagMindGames.Bouncy;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {

private AdView adView;

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "i can't write this";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    View gameView = initializeForView(new Bouncy(), false);

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("77CC5A3A77DE3B76C559F17FC14DFDF1")
        .build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);


    layout.addView(gameView);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);


    setContentView(layout);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a file integers.xml it's already in the google_play_service_lib resources. Could you post the entire logcat errors ?